# Building pytorch on the NVIDIA Jetson Nano developer kit

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm working on a Jetson Nano, and trying to install pytorch 1.4.0 onto it to run some toy experiments.

However, I'm running into a lot of trouble with this. After failing to leverage the prebuilt wheels, I've gone the way of building from scratch, but after a couple hours, it fails with the following error.

```
[3249/3931] Building NVCC (Device) object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o
FAILED: caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o 
cd /home/workingdir/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda && /usr/bin/cmake -E make_directory /home/workingdir/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/. && /usr/bin/cmake -D verbose:BOOL=OFF -D build_configuration:STRING=Release -D generated_file:STRING=/home/workingdir/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/./torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o -D generated_cubin_file:STRING=/home/workingdir/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/./torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o.cubin.txt -P /home/workingdir/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o.Release.cmake
Killed
CMake Error at torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o.Release.cmake:281 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/workingdir/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/./torch_cuda_generated_Unique.cu.o
```

Does anyone know how to interpret this? Did I run out of memory/swap space?

Additionally, if anyone knows of an easier way to get pytorch>=1.1.0 on my nano, any tips would be appreciated :)

I followed this thread here both for the prebuilt installation and the scratch installation: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-nano-version-1-5-0-now-available/72048